# Make reference to a Button in a repeater?

Tags: asp.net, forms, button, reference, repeater

I have a form with a button control in a repeater, and I am trying to reference it in my code so that I can disable and enable it where appropriate but it isn't recognized.

I tried something that looked like this:

```
Sub btnClickPrev(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'Get the reference of the clicked button.
    Dim button As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    'Get the command argument
    Dim commandArgument As String = button.CommandArgument

    'Get the Repeater Item reference
    Dim item As RepeaterItem = CType(button.NamingContainer, RepeaterItem)

    'Get the repeater item index
    Dim index As Integer = item.ItemIndex
    item.Enabled = false

End Sub
```

But item.enabled didn't work like btnPrev.enabled=false would

And this is what I have in my button form control:

```
  asp:Button ID="btnPrev" Text="Previous" OnClick="btnClickPrev" CommandArgument = '1' runat="server"
```

Any help would be appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, `RepeaterItem` doesn't have any `Enable` property that you are trying to change. Instead, loop through all controls inside RepeaterItem and disable them like this:

```
Sub btnClickPrev(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'Get the reference of the clicked button.
    Dim button As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    'Get the Repeater Item reference
    Dim item As RepeaterItem = CType(button.NamingContainer, RepeaterItem)    

    For Each con In item.Controls
        'Disable button
        If TypeOf con Is Button Then
            CType(con, Button).Enabled = False
        End If

        'Disable other controls if you want
        If TypeOf con Is CheckBox Then
            CType(con, CheckBox).Enabled = False
        End If
    Next

    'item.Enabled = False 'Wouldn't work

End Sub
```